# Key error due to missing row numbers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a pandas dataframe (`df`) like the following

```
row_num
0                                  [535, 874, 879, 2062]
1                          [419, 1736, 1827, 2432, 2435]
2                               [1340, 1345, 1805, 2157]
4                                  [555, 888, 999, 2222]
5                                     [1305, 1606, 2781]
6                                                  [270]
9                                           [2129, 2163]
```

There are missing numbers in the first column, `row_num` (e.g. `3, 7, 8`)  The second column of the dataframe contains lists. I want to use to **construct a list of lists from the entries (lists) of the second column**. This is what I am trying now:

```
LoL = [df[i] for i in range(len(df))]
```

But, I get errors (`KeyError: 3`) because of the missing row numbers. How can I get a construct a list of lists from the second column of my dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DON'T loop over your dataframe, it is highly inefficient. Assuming the second row is named `'second row name'`, you can make a list of lists using the following command:

```
df['second row name'].values.tolist()
```

Edit: It looks that you may actually be working with a series instead of a dataframe. You would use the following command since it is already a series:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

As @W-B commented - you actually don't need to do `df.values.tolist()` as `df.tolist()` is sufficient.

Comment: Looks like the second row doesn't have a name. The data frame is like the example that I have given in the question.

Comment: If the second row does not have a name, you are probably working with a series. Use the following command: `df.values.tolist()`.

Comment: using df.tolist() no need values.

Comment: Joe: Thanks for your help. I tried this `LoL = [df.values[i] for i in range(len(df.values))]` and it worked.

Comment: W-B : Thanks for your help. Your suggestion works. Will you like to put your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy no need since Joe already included , and mission complete :-) happy coding ~

Comment: @W-B I have always just done `s.values.tolist()` when `s.tolist()` is actually just sufficient. So something that I learned today, thanks!

Comment: Many thanks Joe and W-B. Belated Happy New Year to both of you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways of doing this:

So the dataframe I've created is:

```
   row_num                       datalist
0        0          [535, 874, 879, 2062]
1        1  [419, 1736, 1827, 2432, 2435]
2        2       [1340, 1345, 1805, 2157]
3        4          [555, 888, 999, 2222]
4        5             [1305, 1606, 2781]
5        6                          [270]
6        9                   [2129, 2163]
```

Directly convert to list as [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8345749/joe-patten) mentioned:

```
df.values.tolist() 
or 
df['second row name'].values.tolist()
```

Whichever suits the type of data you have.

The other way was exactly what you were doing actually, just instead of taking range of length, just use the values:

```
[a for a in k.datalist.values]
```

And another way is exactly your code, but just use your row_num as index and reindex your values, which will give you index as 0 to ... and then just use your exact code, it will work.